# Ember build adds read permission to some files but not others

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

In my Ember.js project, I have the following files:

```
public/img/pixels.png 0640
public/img/vector.svg 0640
```

I'm deploying this inside a Docker `nginx` container. `COPY`'d files automatically belong to root. Nginx reads files with user `nginx`.

After doing `ember build -prod` in a Docker container, I have the following files:

```
img/pixels-d72816e93259890d380ddf05acb748e7.png 0644
img/vector.svg 0640
```

Notice how the hashed file automatically changed from `0640` to `0644` so it is readable. The other one however is not. It is copied, but not readable.

In this Ember app, all references to `pixels.png` work fine, but references to `vector.svg` result in unavailable images.

1. What causes Ember to add the read bit for some, but not others?
2. **How can I force Ember to set the `a+r` permission for all files it copies from `public`?**
3. Should Ember do this automatically? (e.g. is this a bug?)

Comment: Ember shouldn't alter the file permissions in my opinion. It seems to be related to fingerprinting. I've created an issue to track it: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/8554

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the [issue created in Ember CLI repository](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/8554) after your question here, it should be considered as a bug that these files end up with different permissions. I would recommend to normalize the permissions in another step after building the ember.js application (`ember build -prod`), e.g. `RUN chmod -R 0644 /usr/share/nginx/html`.